# Question about a polynomial's degree

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

How can we show that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $d-1$, then

$$\sum_{k=n_0}^n p(k)$$

is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $d$?

Comment: Don't you need to specify what the coefficients of the polynomials are?

Comment: @Jack M Yes, I should have specified they are integers, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{p(k)}$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $d$, since $\sum_{k=n_0}^{n}{p(k)}$ differs from $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{p(k)}$ by a constant.

Note that $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{k}{d}}=\binom{n+1}{d+1}$$

This can be proven by induction on $n$, or by double counting the number of ways to choose $d+1$ numbers from $\{0, 1, \ldots, n \}$.

Now we induct on $d$:

The base case $d=1$ is clearly true. Suppose that the statement holds for $d=i$, then for a polynomial $p(x)$ with degree $(i+1)-1=i$, we may write $p(x)=a\binom{x}{i}+q(x)$ where $a$ is $i!$ multiplied by the leading coefficient of $p(x)$, and $q(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $i-1$. Then

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{p(k)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{a\binom{k}{i}}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}{q(k)}=a\binom{n+1}{i+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}{q(k)}$$

Note that $a\binom{n+1}{i+1}$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $i+1$, and by the induction hypothesis $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{q(k)}$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $i$.

Therefore $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{p(k)}$ is indeed a polynomial in $n$ of degree $i+1$, and we are done by induction.

Comment: I must say, thank you a thousand times for an xcellent answer. Short and to the point, helped me immensely!Just something I didn't quite get. Why does $p(x)=a\binom{x}{i}+q(x)$ where $a$ is $i$? Could you give me some pointers how this is proved? Do you mean that $\binom{x}{i}=0,1,...,d$ are a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for the integral-valued polynomials, or something along those lines?

Comment: @Vagerman I said that $a$ is $i!$ multiplied by the leading coefficient of $p(x)$. This is so that $p(x)$ and $a\binom{x}{i}$ have the same leading coefficient, so $q(x)$ has degree $i-1$. In essence, this makes use of the fact that every polynomial of degree $n$ may be written as linear combination of $\binom{x}{0}, \binom{x}{1}, \ldots , \binom{x}{n}$.